# Сбой при сравнении двух элементов массива

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь отсортировать список с разными типами

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, float>> rankedScores = scores.ToList();
rankedScores.Sort();
rankedScores.Reverse();
var firstTenItems = rankedScores.Take(10);
```

Но выходит ошибка на строку с методом sort: "Сбой при сравнении двух элементов массива". Если невозможно отсортировать при помощи метода sort, то как это можно сделать?

Comment: приведите, пожалуйста, полный текст исключения.

Comment:     rankedScores.Sort((x, y) => y.Key.CompareTo(x.Key)); 

От того, что c чем сравниваете, зависит порядок сортировки (то есть, Reverse потом вызывать уже не нужно)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Ответ @skyboy, из комментария к другому ответу:

Ну мне требуется, чтобы в списке были элементы разного типа. 
Решается это при помощи

```
static int Compare1(KeyValuePair<string, int> a, KeyValuePair<string, int> b)
{ 
    return a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key); 
}

static int Compare2(KeyValuePair<string, int> a, KeyValuePair<string, int> b) 
{
    return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value); 
}
```

Выбираем по чему сортировать, по ключи или значению:

```
rankedScores.Sort(Compare1)
```

или же

```
rankedScores.Sort(Compare2)
```

---

Кроме вызова [`List<T>.Sort(Comparison<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx) можно также использовать [`List<T>.Sort(IComparer<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx) с передачей полноценного объекта-компарера, а не просто для сравнения значений.

Answer (score 0):

Используй `OrderByDescending` из Linq.